# 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, put

```
    function update(){
    var data = $form_value;
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.knackhq.com/v1/scenes/scene_93/views/view_848/records/542bdc7a1e953ed90509aeab",
      type: "PUT",
      headers: {"X-Knack-Application-Id": "", "X-Knack-REST-API-Key":""},
      data: data,
      success: function(response) { 
        alert('Record created');
        console.log($form_value);
      }
    });
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting Internal server 500 error, url seams to be corect because it works with GET.

Comment: contact **https://api.knackhq.com/** administrator for that error. if you have server side code put it here..

Comment: if it works with GET it doesn't mean it will work with PUT

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error occurring on a server for which the OP hasn't posted code.

Answer (score 0):

500 means there is a problem internal to the server. There's nothing you can do about that other than contact the people who run it and ask whats going on.

Comment: This should be comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think type: "POST" instead of type: "GET" should work for you

Comment: I tried so many combinations that I have feeling I'm gona get sick lol. Any volunteers wana see full code , need a partner on this one im over my head .

Comment: Is the doPost() method being implemented in your servlet?